# activity app confuses calories with kilojoules

Tags: ios

Why does the activity app confuse calories with KJ?

[image]

Comment: I don't use the Activity app and this is just an educated guess, but it seems that it's using "calories" simply as a header for "energy burned", and kilojoules as the actual units. Whether it uses kilocalories/Calories or kilojoules is a setting in the relevant section of the app.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Asking why apple does X is generally off topic. Could you edit this to explain what you are trying to accomplish specifically given your statement - this likely won't get closed.

Comment: If it's deemed to be a question about a design decision Apple made and those questions aren't allowed then close it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no confusion. The app is displaying accurate information. Do you live (or operate your iPhone) outside the UK or US? Most (if not all) countries use the KJ (kilojoule) as a measurement. 1 Calorie (technically kiloCalorie) = 4.184 kilojoules.

Perhaps this app has settings where it can display the kiloCalorie value instead of the KJ value. More information on kiloCalories/kilojoules can be found [at this link](http://www.freedieting.com/calories_nutrition.htm).

Comment: No it's clearly wrong. A calorie isn't joule.

Comment: Well, the web page I linked to clearly explains the mathematical and physical equivalence between kiloCalories and kilojoules. What don't you understand? My wife, an MD who has been a nutritionist for decades, agrees with me.

Comment: They're different units. If I wrote "Miles: 100km" would that make sense?

Comment: This is an issue with how they app is presenting the information in a way _you_ can understand. I'm done here.